# Referencing variables and functions from different directories

Tags: matlab, directory

I am using MATLAB and working in a folder (C:\Matlab\MainFolder) that contains all my 'm' & 'mat' files. However the folder is becoming clustered with to many files.

What I would like to do is create two sub folders - 'data_structs' and 'misc_functions' and be able to reference these files whilst working in my 'MainFolder'. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.mat` files do not need to be in your current working folder; you may put them in the `data_structs` subfolder, and reference them with relative paths, like `'.\data_structs\data_struct1.mat'` in your code.

The best way is to organize your code (i.e. your `.m` files) is to put them in package folders. These create namespaces in matlab, if the folder containing them is curretnly active or in the Matlab path. To do this create the folder `+misc_functions` (though you might want to chose a better name for that). Supposed you have the function `f1()` defined in the file `f1.m` in this package folder. To call this function in you main script/function, you'd use something like `misc_functions.f1()`.

More on organizing code [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html) (the info is valid for procedural programming also, though is classified in OOP section).

Answer (score 1):

A simple method to do this is to use the 'genpath' command. Use:

```
addpath(genpath('C:\Matlab\MainFolder'))
```

This will add **ALL** subfolders of C:\Matlab\MainFolder to the search path.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [wrapper for `genpath`](https://github.com/ssordopalacios/matlab-genpath2) that allows you to exclude specified pattern of directories from the output of `genpath`. Although I do prefer to package functions with the `+` notation, both for making the function names shorter and because they are on the path when you enter the folder, this could be another option if you need to add *most* of the folders but not all of them.